# Is it possible to turn express server serving react frontend into desktop app using electron?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, electron, mern

I have made a web app using express and react, and I want to bundle it into a desktop application, is this possible using electron?

Comment: Have you been able to pack the reactjs front end with the express backend in one electron app?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the tutorial at: https://www.electronforge.io/guides/framework-integration/react

This isn't too hard actually, you can find all instructions you need in https://www.electronforge.io/

To accomplish this, either your app keeps hosting it with express locally and electrons connects to localhost, or even better, do it by not hosting any servers and just keeping your JSX and html files in your project.

If you're using TypeScript and ES6, also consider taking a look here for some examples: https://www.electronforge.io/templates/typescript-+-webpack-template

Comment: Thanks allot @gemsvido going the serverless route is interesting is that detailed in electronforge??

Comment: or explain it some more if you're feeling up to it 

Comment: @CarterJames Yes, the serverless route is detailed in https://www.electronforge.io/

Comment: Sure, I'll explain it a lil. There's a "Getting Started" thing at https://www.electronforge.io/ , and it shows you how to do a tutorial template. Generate that tutorial template, and you'll see how it works. It's really not too complicated, you just include some of your HTML in ./src/ and use Electron to loadFile